# How to use X.509 certificate generated on TPM for Azure DPS on Linux and C#

Tags: azure-iot-hub

We have embedded linux devices running .NET Core 3.1 that we want to provision with Azure DPS.
We have a special use case that requires us to use X.509 certificates for device authentication and we want to use the same certificates for device provisioning with Azure DPS.
The CSR is generated on a hardware TPM on the device and signed by a company CA, which is registered in DPS and we have an enrollment group set up for this CA.

Now how can we use this device certificate (public .pem on disk, private key on TPM) for device provisioning? We only found examples using either a full certificate on disk (public and private key in .pfx) or using a TPM with EK enrollment (which we don't want to do, because the manufacturing process is already designed for X.509).

In other words: Is there a way to create an instance of the needed X509Certificate2 class with the public .pem file and pointing it to the TPM for the private key?

Comment: Hi ElDani, did you ever get to create that X509Certificate class that pointing to the TPM for the private key? I am pondering the exact question.

Comment: Hello Frank, no unfortunately not. We ended up using TPM attestation with EK for authentication with DPS and additionally a X.509 certificate for our other use case that has its keypair protected by the TPM using OpenSSL with [tpm2-tss-engine](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss-engine).
Our conclusion was that this feature would require forking and modifying the .NET Core runtime or getting Microsoft to support it, but it would not have been worth that time and effort since it was less effort to integrate TPM provisioning into the manufacturing process.
Regards, Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply. I  assume the additional X509 certificate you mentioned was not integrated with the DotNet Core framework but some other application? I managed to integrate Nginx with a private key persisted in the TPM using tpm2-tss-engine. But unfortunately, it is half of my problem.

Comment: Yes that's right, our initial plan was to use one certificate for DPS provisioning and OpenVPN connection for remote service purposes. Now we use the certificate only for OpenVPN, which supports OpenSSL with tpm2-tss-engine. We did however get in touch with a Microsoft representative regarding X.509 certificate and TPM who pointed us to [this page](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/master/provisioning/Samples/device#provisioning-devices-using-x509-certificate-based-attestation) where they talk about the SecurityProviderX509 extension model.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't seem to work on Linux and .NET Core, because the PrivateKey setter of X509Certificate2 throws a PlatformNotSupportedException and is forced to an instance of RSAOpenSSL deep down in the .NET Core runtime, which would not be a problem if RSAOpenSSL would support tpm2-tss-engine (At least I did not find a way without modifying the runtime). At this point I stopped investigating and we agreed with our Microsoft contact that we will go a different path. Anyway, I'm sorry I couldn't help you more and I hope you are more lucky than me if you really rely on this.

Comment: Again, Thank you Danial. You helped me a tremendous amount. I was about to embark on the journey of modifying the runtime and force the TPM integration. Sometime, knowing when and where to stop is important. I thank you for all the inputs. Regards

Comment: @FrankLiu Today we talked about this topic again and one colleague brought an idea: It might be possible to set tpm2-tss-engine as the default engine via the global OpenSSL config and indeed when I looked at the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man5/config.html) there is such a section. I'm not sure if I understood it correctly but I think you should set `default_algorithms = ALL` in the `[engine_section]` for tpm2_tss_engine. Since we know that .NET Core uses OpenSSL this could be the solution. If you try it and it works we would be glad if you leave us a comment here. Regards